# What is the EJB 2.x Support End Date?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-2.x

Does anyone know what the Java Support End date for EJB2.X is?

All I could find is [this roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html), which doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Just curious, are you still using EJB?